# Should the [breath] tag be renamed to [breathing]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, rename-request

The usage guidance for the [breath](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breath) tag currently says:

> For questions related to to the act of breathing or holding your breath.

However, any time I see the tag, it takes me a second (or takes me hovering over the tag to see the usage guidance) to remember what it's meant to be used for. The name seems more evocative of breath weapons than the act of breathing itself.

As such, I'm suggesting the tag be renamed to [breathing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breathing). It seems more logical a name for a tag meant to refer to the act of breathing (or not breathing).

Do others agree with my suggestion? Am I just a weirdo? (Maybe both?)

---

After about two weeks with +10/0 votes on renaming and no contrary position expressed, I've gone ahead and renamed. Thanks for noticing and posting! -n60

Comment: FYI: if we do this rename it should be done by diamond moderators, who can rename tags on the spot without bumping questions. That lets us avoid bumping 11 questions to the front page like retagging would do.

Comment: @doppelspooker: Makes sense!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes, it should be renamed.

Without checking, and given the context of RPGs, I would definitely think "breath weapons!" before thinking "breathing" on reading a "breath" tag. Using "breathing" instead effectively removes any ambiguity without compromising the meaning or readability.

Comment: Is there a breath weapon tag? One [\[breath\] question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104111/42375) is about breath weapons.

Comment: @Laurel: I don't think such a tag exists at the moment. [There definitely seem to be enough related questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=breath+weapon+is%3Aquestion) that such a tag would make sense to create, though :)